# How to handle general exception in flask at single place?

Tags: python, exception, flask

I am using `flask`, here giving example, what I want to do. I copied code from flask portal.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Running the app

```
(py35) root@localhost:tmp root$ flask run
 * Serving Flask app "hello"
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Send request

```
root@localhost:~ root$ curl http://localhost:5000/
Hello, World!
```

I modify my function and change it to raise error.

```
@app.route('/')
    def hello_world():
        print(xyz)
        return 'Hello, World!'
```

When i try to send request, it failed

```
[2017-11-06 10:22:13,625] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/nile2691/sbdev/StorageCenterUI/.tox/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/private/tmp/hello.py", line 6, in hello_world
    print(xyz)
NameError: name 'xyz' is not defined
```

I have can add `try...except` in my code, but in real code, its in many place, and I dont want to handle this general exception everywhere.

Is there any way like

```
try:
    process_flask_request()
except Exception as ex:
    # Log detail exception
    logger.exception(ex)
    return "Custome error message for all general exception"
```

With this changes, instead of getting general error like below

```
curl http://localhost:5000/
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

I want to return proper output, with custom error message.

Comment: Maybe you want to check this one out http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/errorpages/

Comment: This topic is well documented: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/errorhandling/#application-errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include error handlers like this, e.g. for displaying the internal server error in your example more nicely:

```
import traceback

(...some code...)

@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_error(e):
    """
    handle internal errors nicely
    """
    tb = traceback.format_exc()
    return render_template('error.html',
                           error=e.message,
                           traceback=tb), 500
```

In your template you can then output the short error message, and (maybe depending on user rights if you have user management) the detailed stacktrace.

As mentioned in the comments on your question, you should read the documentation to get the full picture.